# Facebook Connect / Graph - problems in Internet Explorer with fb:login dialog (not closing)

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I have developed an facebook application for PHP. It is working fine on all browser except IE8.

```
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId   : '<?php echo $facebook->getAppId(); ?>',
          session : <?php echo json_encode($session); ?>, // don't refetch the session when PHP already has it
          status  : true, // check login status
          cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
        });

        // whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      };

      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>
```

an in header i have written

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

it display popup with

```
http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=3#cb=fcd4e0bda699ab&origin=http%3A%2F%2Ffunkyhousemusic.com.au%2Ff2a3a0d311c1622&relation=opener&transport=flash&frame=f11105d2b30fcb8&result=%7B%22perms%22%3A%22publish_stream%22%2C%22selected_profiles%22%3A100001565152261%2C%22session%22%3A%22%7B%5C%22session_key%5C%22%3A%5C%222.AQCSnIWiw1JjiNd1.3600.1308553200.1-100001565152261%5C%22%2C%5C%22uid%5C%22%3A%5C%22100001565152261%5C%22%2C%5C%22expires%5C%22%3A1308553200%2C%5C%22secret%5C%22%3A%5C%227vpbXmKCQvEOb_tVEdBXpA__%5C%22%2C%5C%22base_domain%5C%22%3A%5C%22funkyhousemusic.com.au%5C%22%2C%5C%22access_token%5C%22%3A%5C%22161903587201698%7C2.AQCSnIWiw1JjiNd1.3600.1308553200.1-100001565152261%7CfW98-D_hw--lS8NdRCxdU51N-eA%5C%22%2C%5C%22sig%5C%22%3A%5C%22766d1359acfdb68b0226c6187413b05f%5C%22%7D%22%7D
```

any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 2):

My facebook login button stopped working for IE8 recently as well.  The button worked previously so I think Facebook may have recently updated their SDK with something that broke their previous fixes for the issue (I saw similar reports dating back 3 years).

After trying a lot of suggestions from others nothing worked except one, and that was using a custom channel url by adding it to your FB.init function.  In the documentation the reasons they give for using it don't cover this particular issue, but using it did work for me.  The FB.init documentation can be found at:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/

Basically all you have to do is add a reference to a channel.html file in your FB.init function.

```
FB.init({
         appId  : 'YOURAPPID',
         status : true,
         cookie : true,
         xfbml  : true,
         channelUrl : document.location.protocol + '//YOURDOMAIN/channel.html', 
       });
```

And then create the channel.html file at the location you specified (doesn't have to be in the top level folder, '//domain/some_path/channel.html' will work too) and inside the file have just this one line.

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Comment: You saved my day! The page kept refreshing on IE7, but now it's fixed. :D

Comment: Just to add to this -- you can change the script tag in the .html file to `<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>` in order to not have to do any "server side stuff within the channel.html file".

Comment: Thanks @technophile, that does make it a lot easier.  I updated my answer with that addition.